# understanding gödel's 1931 paper - gödel numbers

Tags: logic, incompleteness

I am a little confused about gödel numbers and what numbers exactly we are manipulating.

are the numbers "real" natural numbers (than we obviously represent as) 1, 2, ... or are we always dealing with numbers in the "format" "succ( ... succ(0) ... )" ?

Like are we manipulating genuine natural numbers or their representation in the system at hand ?

I don't have a mathematical background, i'm just a curious guy so it may be a silly question, i feel like their is a difference between "real" numbers, whatever they may be, and their representation, and i'm getting confused about what is manipulated, using what system, etc.

I heard about models and stuff but i may be mixing up everything.

for example, for the 45-th primitive recursive function : "provable(x)", or "
"Bew(x)", is x a real natural number of a number in the "format" "succ( ... succ(0) ... )" ?

"R(x) ≡ 2x" and "(n+1) N x" makes me believe we are using natural numbers "outside" of the system introduced by Gödel, but we could be working with numbers encoded in the system : "succ( ... (succ(0) ... )". i feel like for some reason we shouldn't work outside of the system.

Am i wrong ? Does that make any difference ?

Comment: So, you're reading Godel's original paper – where? In his collected works? In van Heijenoort's anthology *From Frege to Godel*? elsewhere? I think that's commendable. Godel is very readable.

Comment: from the internet, primarily here :
http://hirzels.com/martin/papers/canon00-goedel.pdf

and here : 
http://mrob.com/pub/math/goedel.html

Comment: I am curious, i think everybody could and should be able to understand great mathematical and scientific work.

I think it's a shame this knowledge seems to be reserved to some kind of intellectual / academic elite.

I'm just "another" computer programmer with not much of a college math or serious computer science background, but i'm craving for that knowledge. I think A LOT of people are too, even the "average Joe" (why are documentary so successful if that was not the case).

I hope soon i understand every detail of it, make it intuitive and acessible and share it to ANYone.

Comment: It feels like reading and writing.

For a long time it was reserved to an elite. Now it's a given in our modern society for anyone to be able to read and write one another, exchange ideas.

It should be the same for those great scientific works.

Publish it / Make it accessible so that it is understandable/exchangeable by anyone.

Comment: Thanks. I got excited on reading the intro to the first -- that he would be translating the paper, modernizing notation and providing commentary. My spirits sagged when I saw his first few comments: "improvable" ! instead of "unprovable". Unfortunately "improvable" is already taken in English and means something quite different. Sigh. The next link isn't as easy on the eyes but I it offers useful commentary and I prefer it.

Comment: Getting a look at this paper again, yes to what I said in a comments under my answer: all of 1. through 46. are formulas defined in the formal system. He builds up the machinery needed for 46, the "Bew(x)" formula, representing "x is provable". Note that when he speaks of "number-theoretic functions" and relations, he means the actual mathematical entities. His term for what I called "numerals" is "number-sign".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Collecting my comments into one answer.)

You're right to sweat the details on this: The entire proof is about the boundary between what can be said in a formal system, what can be proved in it, and the outside world (of abstract entities) which it attempts to characterize. So it's essential to maintain clarity about these things, and draw a sharp distinction between strings in the formal system and what they denote or evaluate to.

Within the formal system, the things that get substituted into a formula such as $Bew(w)$ are numerals, and not integers (actual numbers). They're representations of integers within the formal system, terms/expressions which denote integers. A *Godel numbering* is a particular way of assigning numbers to terms and formulas of a particular formal system, provided the system contains enough arithmetic to make that possible. The integer assigned to a formula is *its Godel number*. 
See the answer by @Mauro ALLEGRANZA for a little more detail, and in particular the link he provides re *arithmetization of syntax*, the key notion.

Finally, a note on terminology: "integers" rather than "real numbers". In math "the real numbers" denotes that set of numbers, $\mathbb{R}$, generally taken together with additional structure (addition, multiplication, and the usual "<" relation). The real numbers include the integers, all rationals such as $\frac 2 3, \frac {513} {153}, - \frac 5 7$ etc., as well as irrationals like $\pi$.

Comment: So if i'm right, the 45 functions and afterwards always manipulate so called "numerals", i.e. "names" for naturals numbers in the system at hand, and we are never working "outside" of the system ... right ?



And about the notation : yeah i was confusing, obviously i meant "integers" for "real natural numbers", i know the difference between "real numbers", "rationals" and "integers" but i was not being clear enough

Comment: The 45 functions are defined within the system, and others are then derived from them within the system by composition, via substitution of terms for variables. That's all carried out within the formal system, yes.

Comment: i realized only now that you already answered my question but by the time i read your answer first, i didn't know the distinction between a (natural) number and a numeral.

Now it seems more clear in my head. I will read the paper once again, try to find results myself and see if it all clicks.

Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

The basic intuition behind Gödel's proof is the [arithmetization of syntax](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/#AriForLan).

The language is made of *symbols* : $\lnot, \lor, \forall, 0, f, \ldots$.

The language is the *first-order* language of arithmetic. Thus, a *term* (e.g. $f(0)$) in the language is a "name" denoting a *number* (the number $1$) and a *sentence* (a closed formula, like : $\lnot (fx_1 = 0)$ ) express an arithmetical fact (the fact that $0$ has no predecessor).

The "trick" of encoding allows us to use arithmetical relations as a way to express relations between "syntactical" objects, like the *provability* predicate $Bew(x)$.

*Gödel numbers* are natural numbers : in your previous post we have seen how to "compute" them.

The *provability* predicate $Bew(n)$ holds **iff** $n$ is the code of a formula $\varphi$ that is provable in the formal system $\mathsf P$, i.e. with $n= \ulcorner \varphi \urcorner$ :

> > $Bew(\ulcorner \varphi \urcorner)$ **iff** $\mathsf P \vdash \varphi$.

Thus $Bew(x)$ is like any other predicate of natural numbers; like e.g. $Even(x)$, where $Even(n)$ holds **iff** $n$ is even.

By f-o language of arithmetic we can express the predicate $Even(x)$ as follows : $\exists k \ (n=f(f(0)) \times k)$.

In the same way, Gödel's proof shows how to "build" a formula (a very complicated one indeed) able to express "inside" the system $\mathsf P$ the arithmetical facts encoding the "syntactical" facts regarding $\mathsf P$ itself, like the fact that a specific formula is an axiom of the system or the fact that a certain sequence of formulae is a proof in the system.

This "double play" is cleraly sated by Gödel at the ouset of his paper :

> The formulas of a formal system in outward appearance are finite sequences of 
>   primitive signs (variables, logical constants, and parentheses or punctuation dots), and it is easy to state with complete precision *which* sequences of primitive signs are meaningful formulas and which are not. Similarly, proofs, from a formal point of view, are nothing but finite sequences of formulas (with certain specifiable properties.) Of course, for metamathematical considerations it does not matter what objects are chosen as primitive signs, and we shall assign natural numbers to this use. Consequently, a formula win be a finite sequence of natural numbers, and a proof array a finite sequence of finite sequences of natural numbers. The metamathematical notions (propositions) thus become notions (propositions) about natural numbers or sequences of them; therefore they can (at least in part) be expressed by the symbols of the 
>   system itself. In particular, it can be shown that the notions "formula", "proof 
>   array", and "provable formula" can be defined in the system; that is, we can, 
>   for example, find a formula $F(v)$ with one free variable $v$ such that $F(v)$, interpreted according to the meaning of the terms of [the system], says: $v$ is a provable formula. We now construct an undecidable proposition of the system, that is, a proposition $A$ for which neither $A$ nor *not*-$A$ is provable. [...]
>
> From the remark that $[R(q); q]$ says about itself that it is not provable it follows at once that $[R(q) ; q]$ is true, for $[R(q) ; q]$ is indeed unprovable (being undecidable). Thus, the proposition that is undecidable *in the system* still was decided by metamathematical considerations.

---

For a "classical" textbook with all the details of Gödel's proof (very much in the same "style" of Gödel's original paper), see :

- Elliott Mendelson, [Introduction to mathematical logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=ZO1p4QGspoYC&pg=PA190) (4th ed - 1997), page 190-on.

For a complete introduction to this topic, see :

- Peter Smith, [An Introduction to Gödel's Theorems](https://books.google.it/books?id=-SBpYKebkJMC&printsec=frontcover) (2nd ed 2013).

For a divulgative books (without errors) see :

- Torkel Franzén, [Gödel's theorem : An incomplete guide to its use and abuse](https://books.google.it/books?id=71pK8Zz9Dd8C) (2005)

and :

- Francesco Berto, [There's Something about Gödel : The Complete Guide to the Incompleteness Theorem](https://books.google.it/books?id=jmDneXkHxm4C) (2009).

Comment: So if i'm right, the 45 functions and afterwards always manipulate so called "numerals", i.e. "names" for naturals numbers in the system at hand, and we are never working "outside" of the system ... right ? 

And the codes we talked about in my previous question are numerals (like using the notation in [http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/#AriForLan] ) all numbers used in the paper (at least the 45 function and after) would/should be written with a bar underneath, right ?

Comment: Thank you for your very useful links

Comment: @josephM'Bimbi-Bene - Yes and No... Every expression in the language has a "meaning" : the *numeral* $\overline 0$ denotes the *number* $0$. When G defines the formula 1 : $x/y$ meaning "$x$ is divisible by $y$" it is a formula of the language : $(∃z)[z ≤ x \land x = y.z]$ that holds for *numbers* $n, m$ iff $n$ divides $m$.

Comment: using hirzels.com/martin/papers/canon00-goedel.pdf
But since provable(x) uses proofFor(x,y), which uses item(n,x), which uses prFactor(n,x), which uses isPrime(x), which uses the first function "y | x" (one could write it as "divisible(y,x)" ),

and since (if i didn't misinterpret you) this very first formula applies on "numbers" and not "numerals" (or number-signs), then 1-46 work outside of the system.

Or you mean that x/y is built on the language, but "acts" as we would expect on the "divisibility" property, about "actual" numbers, i.e. outside of the (syntactic ?) system ?